# How to show a feed of Github revisions that updates automatically?

Tags: github, feed, live, revisions

I'm wondering how you could make a feed on your website that shows all revisions in a Github project. Basically something like this: https://oc.tc/revisions is what I'm looking for. I couldn't find the scripts/programs they use anywhere sadly.

Any help is appreciated,

Martin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is two ways to do that. You can either use the [GitHub API for Commits](http://developer.github.com/v3/repos/commits/), which responds with JSON, or you can simply take the Atom feed of the repo. Each repo has an feed with the commits, the Feed URL looks this way:

```
https://github.com/[Username]/[Repository]/commits/[Branch].atom
```

For just displaying the "revision", using the feed will be a quite straightforward solution. Using the API offers you more options, though.